# How to get negative text shadow (Android)

Tags: android, styling, css

I want my text shadow to appear reverse (above the text) rather than below the text. Is there a way to have a negative "Dy" value like I have below?

```
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0</item>
```

Comment: can you explain what happens when you try this?

Comment: have you tried using 2 instead of -1?

Comment: When I use a negative instead of positive, No shadow appears. using a value of 2 simply makes the shadow 2 px down

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that shadowRadius needs to be non-zero in order for the shadow to be visible.  The following code works for me to achieve a red shadow above the text:

```
<item name="android:shadowColor">#ffff0000</item>
<item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
<item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
<item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
```